# How to maintain spaces between menus and set different text color for selected and unselected state using iCarousel?

Tags: ios, swift, icarousel

I need to maintain each menu text spaces (leading + trailing) value with 10-15 pixels. And only selected row text color should be white, Otherwise rest of things are should be white withAlphaComponent value 0.4. It's all need to done with using iCarousel.

Initially I was tried to achieve using like https://github.com/hightower/HTHorizontalSelectionList in my current working project which is constructing on Swift 4.1 version.

Unfortunately I can't achieve using HTHorizontalSelectionList, because In my case horizontal selection indicator should be centered. Only selected menus were moving when click or scrolling it. So that's the reason I shifted with iCarousel. It's almost I reached 90% of work except that couple of requirements.

Here below what I tried it on iCarousel,

```
        carouselView.delegate = self
    carouselView.dataSource = self
    carouselView.type = .linear
    carouselView.isPagingEnabled = true
    carouselView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    carouselView.clipsToBounds = true;
    carouselView.bounces = false
    carouselView.decelerationRate = 0.6; //0.6;//0.885;
    carouselView.reloadData()
    carouselView.centerItemWhenSelected = true
    carouselView .scrollToItem(at: 1, animated: false)
```

// MARK: iCarousel DeataSoure & Delegates

```
extension WCPPageViewController: iCarouselDataSource, iCarouselDelegate {
func numberOfItems(in carousel: iCarousel) -> Int {
    return items.count
}

func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAt index: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {

    var label: UILabel
    label = UILabel(frame: CGRect (x: 0, y: 0, width: 165, height: 80))
    label.backgroundColor = .clear
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.font = UIFont.WCPMontserratBold(size: 40)
    label.tag = 1
    label.textColor = UIColor.white
    label.text = "\(items[index])"
    return label
}

func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, didSelectItemAt index: Int) {

    redirectToOtherPageControllerClass(curentIndex: CGFloat(index))

    if currentIndex == 0 {
        updateTeamSwitchBtnLEadingAnchorValue(leadingValue: 10)
    }
    else
    {
        updateTeamSwitchBtnLEadingAnchorValue(leadingValue: -50)
    }
}

func carouselCurrentItemIndexDidChange(_ carousel: iCarousel) {

    redirectToOtherPageControllerClass(curentIndex: CGFloat(carousel.currentItemIndex))

    if carousel.currentItemIndex == 0 {
        updateTeamSwitchBtnLEadingAnchorValue(leadingValue: 10)
    }
    else
    {
        updateTeamSwitchBtnLEadingAnchorValue(leadingValue: -50)
    }
}

func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, itemTransformForOffset offset: CGFloat, baseTransform transform: CATransform3D) -> CATransform3D {
    //implement 'flip3D' style carousel
    let transformCopy = CATransform3DRotate(transform, CGFloat(.pi / 8.0), 0.0, 0.5, 0.0)

    return CATransform3DTranslate (transformCopy, 0, 0, offset * carousel.itemWidth)
}

func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, valueFor option: iCarouselOption, withDefault value: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {

    switch (option) {

    case .wrap:
        return 0

    case .fadeMin:
        return -0.4//-1.5

    case .fadeRange:
        return 1.0

    case .visibleItems:
        return 3.0

    case .fadeMax:
        return 0.4//1.0

    case .spacing:
        return 0.9

    default:
        return value
    }
}}
```

I have tried to adjust values on this datasource, func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, valueFor option: iCarouselOption, withDefault value: CGFloat) -> CGFloat  - for ".spacing:" maintain 10 - 15 pixels in between each menu text's.

And also I have adjusted ".fadeMin:, .fadeRange: and .fadeMax:" for selected row text color should be white and rest of menu's text color "white withAlphaComponent value 0.4". But the output not came what I expected.

**Edited :** 
Just now, I achieved **.fadeMin:, .fadeRange: and .fadeMax:** properties with the help of reading this post - [How can we change the fade color in iCarousel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516746/how-can-we-change-the-fade-color-in-icarousel?rq=1)

Now it's working the selected row and others what I expected.

Still I'm surfing to achieve **.Spacing** property between menu text's.

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly Try like this:

```
   func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, valueFor option: iCarouselOption, withDefault value: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    switch (option) {
        case .spacing: return 8 // 8 points spacing
        default: return value
    }
}
```